# Does a DHCP server assign MAC addresses to network computers?

Tags: linux, dhcp, mac-address

I have been working on basic Linux network configuration. I am aware that IP addresses, default gateways, subnetmasks etc are assigned by a DHCP server but am unsure if MAC addresses are assigned by DHCP. Where do MAC addresses come from if a system is utilising DHCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MAC address is a unique identifier that identifies the hardware (the network card)(the first bytes identify the manufacturer and type, the rest is a serial number). DHCP allocates an IP address to a MAC address.

In other words, on all networks you PC has the same MAC address, but can be given different IP address by the DHCP servers.

The uniqueness of the MAC is sometimes used to whitelist/blacklist computers on a network, although it can be worked around since you can sometimes replace the hardware MAC by an arbitrary value.